# Way to find out how many ordinary vertices lie on path between two special vertices

Tags: c++, graph

I've a graph in which some vertices are special and others are ordinary. I want to find out how many ordinary vertices lies on the path between two special vertices.
For eg.

(X)---P---Q---R---(y)
Q----T---B

X and Y are special vertices and P,Q,T,B are ordinary vertices. Now P,Q and R are ordinary vertices lying on the path between x and y. T is connected to Q and B is connected to T but they do not lie on the path between x and y. Is there a method to find how many ordinary vertices lie on the path between two special vertices.
The special vertices may even be greater than 2 but it is assured that there exists only one path to move from one vertex to other.

Every vertex is reachable from any other vertex but only one path exists between any given pair of vertex.

Comment: If the graph is fully connected, how can there be only one path between any pair of nodes? Did you mean that all edges have a multiplicity of (at most) 1, i.e., there are no parallel edges?

Comment: By fully connected I meant that every vertex is reachable fro any other vertex by some path but it is assured that there is only 1 such path.

Comment: That's not what "fully connected" means. You mean the graph is "connected".

Comment: Yes, I meant that only. I've removed that statement. Thanks for pointing out.